# Expression must be a modifiable lvalue - array in structure

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, struct, callback

I need to pass two arrays (`int[1024][3]`, `int[1024][4]`) and a `Mat*` (OpenCV matrix) to a callback function.
I have such structure:

```
 struct data_holder {
     Mat* mat;
     unsigned int* data[4];
     unsigned int* tara[3];
     //unsigned int tara[1024][3];  //Previous attempt
     //unsigned int data[1024][4];  
 }
```

And this is my assignment:

```
 Opencv_Button pokus = Opencv_Button(20,40,50,20);  //Creating button class instance
 pokus.val("Tara");  //Button title
 ui.addButton(&pokus);  //Adding button to UI
 data_holder but_data; //structure
 but_data.data = &data;  //!!Expression must be a modifiable lvalue!!
 but_data.tara = &tara;  //For unsigned int data[1024][4] in structure I did ... = data
 but_data.mat = &UI_tara;//Matrix assigned with no problems
 pokus.setCallback(taraButtonCallback, (void*)&but_data);
```

So how do I pass two arrays and that Mat object to the callback function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
unsigned int* data[4];
```

Is an array of pointers.  Arrays are not assignable.

Assuming that the type of the RHS is `int [1024][4]`, then I have a feeling that you really want this:

```
unsigned int (*data)[1024][4];
```

Comment: In fact, I think they want `unsigned int (*data)[1024][4];`. They are stricken with the "arrays are not pointers" confusion.